# Why run tomcat7:deploy vs tomcat7:redeploy?

Tags: maven, deployment, tomcat7

Is there any reason to ever run `tomcat7:deploy` instead of `tomcat7:redeploy`? So far, I haven't found anything the deploy can do that the redeploy can't, however, a deploy only fails if the app is deployed already, which needs a redeploy. The redeploy works even after you `tomcat7:undeploy` the app, which should revert it to the most initial stage.

Why does `tomcat7:deploy` exist beside the `redeploy` which seems to do everything it does plus more?

I am using

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-maven-plugin), it seems that the only difference is that `deploy` performs a check to see if the project is already deployed. If it is, the deployment fails. `redeploy` will `undeploy` instead if it finds an already deployed application.

So I don't think `deploy` is all that useful. I can see how it makes sense to use it if for some reason your application can't be hot-reloaded and requires some different process to be taken down. In that case, it would make sense to prefer `deploy` over `redeploy`.